# How is it possible to have a sudden error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

On a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, **without anything reconfigured or reinstalled**, suddenly there is an popup

```
System error detected
```

How is that possible? (***I do not want a precise answer which is not possible, but just all kind of possible causes***).

- Nothing updated
- Nothing new installed
- Nothing reconfigured
- Nothing deleted

ONLY using a browser.

Reminder: ***I DO NOT want an answer to any specific problem. s is a GENRAL question. There is a system that work without errors, and without change the system shows an error. How can that be possible?***

Comment: IBM proved (using stats) that sunspots can cause memory to lose values; thus data centers/centres don't have windows to prevent this - got any windows?   More likely it's a power surge/drop (have good filters on your power) or some event you're not likely to work out; computer equipment isn't perfect & does glitch (maybe a capacitor has started to swell and is moving towards it's EOL - if so it'll occur more often; maybe twice next year/month/week...)  You likely can't know...

Comment: To get information about system errors, the best place to look for the issue in /var/crash/ -- the Problem detected is found there usually (ie. crash dump)

Comment: You misunderstand. I do NOT want to solve the problem. I want to know what possibly can cause a working system to fail from one minut to the other without any visible change? How can that be possible? A working system, I do NOT do ANY change, and then it is not working anymore? How can that be possible at all?

Comment: My first comment gave a possible cause; I don't know how much testing you did of your system before putting it into production, how good your maintenance or how often you check it for failing components (drives, circuits etc), if you have good equipment which keeps temperature & power logs, if you've checked it as it often gives indications of issues in components (as in cards/circuits; not individual electrical-components but replaceable units; if you've a consumer or low-end product though none of this will be available; do you use ECC ram where logs will show, if not you get errors like..)

Comment: @guiverc Never mind. You did not understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a typical Linux system, there are *a lot* of things running in the background. One example is a the whole graphical user interface (GUI), which is (depending on your Ubuntu version and settings) a whole X Window System server or the more modern Wayland. On top of that, there's the desktop environment / window manager you're using like Gnome Shell, KDE or others. There's the cron daemon, that runs maintenance tasks at specified time intervals, and several more. And because you're on a desktop system, we're not even talking about server daemons / services like a webserver, FTP server, database servers etc.

Any one of those has run into an error. The popup you saw should offer you to view additional details about which program / process went belly-up, with what signal and so forth. Without further information, just from "There was some error somewhere", it's basically impossible to detect the cause or recommend any solution.

---

EDIT: As I explained, there are many reasons why some background process can go belly-up. Some arbitrary examples include

- Maybe some resource you use like a server on the internet isn't accessible anymore, changed the address, changed the credentials, doesn't answer fast enough today, etc.
- Maybe some hardware device in your computer is slowly failing. It worked just barely within the specifications the last days, but now it left the specifications and causes an error.
- Maybe some configuration file has been corrupted, maybe because of an irregular shutdown. When a maintenance service tries to parse the file, it gets thrown into a loop. Maybe the last update of a maintenance service that runs weekly or monthly introduced a bug that didn't manifest before, because it's the first time the service ran since the faulty update.
- Maybe your harddisk is filling up, and some task doesn't have enough disk space left.
- Maybe one of the filesystems on one of your disk(s) has bad sectors or other inconsistencies which are found in the routine check.
- Maybe there's a race condition. Let's say task A and B use the same resource. Normally, A is finished when B starts. But today, A has more to do than usual, and the two collide.
- Maybe there are some temporary files that can't be cleaned up because they have the wrong permissions, maybe because you started a program with root permissions.
- Maybe some counter in some program has a overflow, because it has too much data too handle / clean up, it run too often (doesn't work more than 4.096 days in a row or something like this) etc.
- Maybe you normally have an external device plugged in, like an external harddisk or external speakers. Some process tries to access the device (to do a backup, for a startup sound, ...), but the device isn't plugged in today or isn't accessible for some reason.
- Maybe it's really sunny today and your computer is sitting near the window, heating up too much. Or maybe the dust clogged the fans and ventilation over the years.

As I tried to explain, all of this is guesswork without further information about your error.

Comment: I do not want the specific cause. I want to know all possible causes how this can happen, when you do not change anything in your operating system.

Comment: @Alex _All possible causes_? Sorry, I don't think there's that much space on the internet to write that list down ;) Joking aside, a Linux system (basically, any computer) is way too variable to boil it down to one or a few possible causes. We can't know that software you have or have not installed, we can't know what exact hardware the manufacturer has build into your machine, we can't know the specifics of your internet connection, and so on and so forth.

Comment: But the system did work. And without any manual intervention the system does not work anymore. How can that possibly be possible?

Comment: @Alex As I explained above, there's _a lot_ that's going on under the hood. And some part of it went belly-up. Maybe there was a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), maybe something on your computer or on the internet didn't answer fast enough and it caused a timeout, maybe a hardware device in your machine was just barely working before and isn't anymore, maybe... There are thousands and thousands possible causes.

Comment: How can there be the same race condition every time you start the computer? 
But what are SOME of the thousand possible causes? If you can list just 10 you can think of, my question would be answered!

Comment: @Alex So the error you don't want to look into is reproducible after reboots? Nice of you to tell us... But it doesn't really change my answer: There are many possible causes. I edited my answer and listed some of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98418/discussion-between-alex-and-henning-kockerbeck).